# How to pass a view function with arguments in a decorator to another decorator in django

Tags: python, django, view, arguments, decorator

I have been trying to find a solution for this for hours. I have already gone through many [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952641/decorating-decorators-try-to-get-my-head-around-understanding-it) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965607/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-in-a-decorator-to-functions-argument-in-a-decorated-f), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347388/python-passing-a-function-with-parameters-as-parameter). I am using `django-guardian` to implement object level permissions in my django app. I am trying to `implement permission_required decorator dynamically`. The idea is to create another decorator which can switch between permission required decorators and then pass view function to respective permission_required decorator.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', Test.as_view()),
    url(r'(?P<handle>[-\w]+)/(?P<method>[-\w]+)/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/$', Test.as_view(), name='handler'),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
class Test(View):
    @decorator_switch
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Test View')
```

**decorator_switch**

```
from api.mappings.permission_mappings import perm_mappings

def decorator_switch(func):

def wrapper(instance, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    permission_decorator = \
        perm_mappings.get('handles').get(kwargs.get('handle')).get('actions').get(kwargs.get('method'))
    return permission_decorator(func)(request)(args)(kwargs)
return wrapper
```

**permission_mappings**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required as django_perm_req
from api.decorators.guardian_perm_req import permission_required as guardian_perm_req
from pyteam.models import Team

perm_mappings = {
    'handles': {
        'team': {
            'actions':  {
                'get': guardian_perm_req('pyteam.retrieve_team', (Team, 'id', 'id')),
                'create': django_perm_req('pyteams.add_team', raise_exception=True),
                'update': guardian_perm_req('pyteam.change_team', (Team, 'id', 'id')),
                'delete': guardian_perm_req('pyteam.delete_team', (Team, 'id', 'id'))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After this I opened url `http://localhost:8000/team/get/1/` But I got an exception

> GuardianError at /team/get/1/
>
> Argument id was not passed into view function

I checked in kwargs of views as well as kwargs of decorator of decorator switch for id in kwargs and I found it. Then I checked wrapper function of guardian_perm_req but `def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):` of `def decorator(view_func):` was not getting url kwargs which caused this issue.

As decorators and basically functions, I tried calling and returning view functions from decorator switch itself.

```
return permission_decorator(func(instance, request, args, kwargs))
```

But as expected clickjacking middleware raised an exception on this

> AttributeError at /team/get/1/
>
> 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Dis you tried `return permission_decorator(func)(instance, request, *args, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: @L_S my bad, I didn't try that. This fixed my issue. Please post an answer also that I can mark same as correct answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
return permission_decorator(func)(instance, request, *args, **kwargs)
```